# Array length returns zero

Tags: arrays, api, asynchronous

I'm pushing an json response into an array, but for some reason the
console log for the length of the array comes back as 0 even through
there is clearly an object in it.

```
let dogPool = [];

for (i=0; i<dogNumber; i++){
    fetch('https://dog.ceo/api/breeds/image/random')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(responseJSON => dogPool.push(responseJSON))
    .catch(error => alert('error! danger!'));
}

console.log(dogPool); //shows object
console.log(dogPool.length) // returns 0
```

**console:**

```
arrayAPI ran
[]0: {message: "https://images.dog.ceo/breeds/mastiff-english/2.jpg", status: "success"}1: {message: "https://images.dog.ceo/breeds/pembroke/n02113023_3474.jpg", status: "success"}2: {message: "https://images.dog.ceo/breeds/chihuahua/n02085620_326.jpg", status: "success"}length: 3__proto__: Array(0) //length 3, but proto array is 0?
0
```

Comment: `fetch` is happening asynchronously, technically the `push()` code snippet happening later than the `console.log()`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this at the end of the code:

```
setTimeout(function() {console.log(dogPool.length);},2000);
```

Answer (score 0):

I made the function an async function and then added await to the fetch

```
async function arrayAPI(){
    console.log("arrayAPI ran");

    let dogPool = [];
    for (i=0; i<dogNumber; i++){
        await fetch('https://dog.ceo/api/breeds/image/random')
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(responseJSON => dogPool.push(responseJSON))
        .catch(error => alert('error! danger!'));
    }

    console.log(dogPool);
    console.log("length of dogpool: " + dogPool.length);
```